# Horizontal scroll issue in android

Tags: android, gridview, android-listview, horizontalscrollview

I am developing one app which has a horizontal scroll view as parent layout and three child,  2 list view and 1 grid view.

When I run application in landscape mode of tablet the focus is shifted on grid view , not on the 1st element of the layout. I have try to give focus to the 1st element but in vain. Please guide me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks....

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_horoscopedetail"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 

    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/banner"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvGanesha"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/ganeshaspeaks"
            android:textColor="#FFa2a2a2"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvToday"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvGanesha"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/today"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="30sp" />


              <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvdate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvGanesha"
                android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="DATE"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="#52000000"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <requestFocus />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvSign"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/sign"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvSignData"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textIsSelectable="false"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTodayHoroscope"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/today_horoscope"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTodayHoroscopeData"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvBusiness"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/business"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvBusinessData"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFinance"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/finance"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFinanceData"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvHealth"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/health"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvHealthData"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvJob"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/job"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvJobData"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvRomance"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/romance"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvRomanceData"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTravel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/Travel"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTravelData"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="520dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Horoscope"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/horoscopGrid"
            android:layout_width="520dp"
            android:layout_height="440dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:columnWidth="110dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="15dp"
            android:numColumns="4"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="460dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Others"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvothers"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:dividerHeight="11dp"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llOthers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="380dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_birth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <include
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/birthday_forcast" >
            </include>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_astro1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <include
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/astroprofile" >
            </include>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_sunsign"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <include
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/sunsign_compability" >
            </include>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_realationship"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <include
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/relationship" >
            </include>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_vastu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <include
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/fengshui" >
            </include>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_chineseprofile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <include
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/chinese" >
            </include>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_chinesecompability"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <include
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/chinese_compability" >
            </include>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_sport"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <include
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/sport" >
            </include>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_celebrity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <include
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/celebrity" >
            </include>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_tarot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <include
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/tarot" >
            </include>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Team"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/teamGrid"
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="440dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post the code that you have used to implement it.

Comment: thanks but code is to large so can't send it....

Comment: just post the xml. i'm actually quite surprised that you have a working scrollview that parents 3 children. that normally throws a run-time exception

Comment: i post xml file check it